# Rounded corners of NSCollectionViewItem

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionviewitem

Simple question, but I can't find any answers... How I can change corner radius of `NSCollectionViewItem` instance?

Comment: item.layer.cornerRadius. import CoreGraphics.

Comment: @GeneCode here I need to set its property? In `viewDidLayout` of item? Of delegate method in controller that has `NSCollectionView` as subview?

Comment: Should be in the collectionview subclass. (alternatively in the delegate)

Comment: @GeneCode I dont want to subclass `NSCollectionView`, in which delegate method I need to change corner radius?

Comment: itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath i think.

Comment: @GeneCode It doesn't work

Comment: Did you set the item background color?

Comment: If you set the item bg color, then you need to set [item.layer setMaskToBounds:YES];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view` of `NSCollectionViewItem` doesn't have layer by default. You need to set `wantsLayer` to `true`, for example:

```
import Cocoa

class TestCellItem: NSCollectionViewItem {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
    }

    override func viewDidLayout() {
        super.viewDidLayout()
        view.layer?.cornerRadius = 20
    }
}
```